# Restriction of a a function

Tags: real-analysis

I have $f: [-1,1] \rightarrow R$.

If $f_{|[-1,0]}(x)$ and $f_{|[0,1]}(x) $ are two increasing restrictions  then f is increasing?

Comment: Take right hand less for contradiction. You need some more restrictions on whole $[-1,1]$

Comment: What about $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}x+1&\text{if }x\in[-1,0]\\x&\text{if }x\in(0,1]\end{cases}\;\;?$$

Comment: if I consider $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $y=\frac{1}{4}$ I have $x<y$ but $f(x)>f(y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $u \leq v$. If $u,v \in [0,1]$ or $u,v \in [-1,0]$ it is clear that $f(u) \leq f(v)$. If $v\in [0,1]$ or $u \in [-1,0]$ then $f(u) \leq f(0)\leq f(v)$.

If are talking about strictly increasing functions then also the result is true by a similar argument.